# How to get canvas size every time it changes its size in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to write a script that changes the size of my image according to the size of the canvas. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import PhotoImage

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg="white", border=0)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

HH = canvas.winfo_reqheight()
WW = canvas.winfo_reqwidth()

print(HH,WW)

img = PhotoImage(file="competeButton.png", master=root)
img = img.zoom(2,2)
panel = Label(canvas, image=img, borderwidth=0)
panel.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")
root.mainloop()
```

As you can see, it sets the button size to what the window size is original. But how would I have it update in real-time? I think it may have to do with the img.zoom.

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind a function to the `<Configure>` event of the widget.

Here's an example which prints the size of the canvas whenever it changes:

```
import tkinter as tk

def canvas_changed(event):
    canvas.itemconfigure("dimensions", text=f"{event.width}x{event.height}")

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
foo = canvas.create_text(10, 10, anchor="nw", text="foo", tags=("dimensions",))
canvas.bind("<Configure>", canvas_changed)

canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have an idea of how I can store the changed width and the height in a variable?

Comment: @Haversine: I don't know what you mean. There's nothing specia. you need to do, just store it in a variable like anything else. You can either save what's in `event.width` or the result of `canvas.winfo_width()`.

Comment: What I mean byt storing it in a variable is by setting the value of the widht in something such as "WW". so WW will always contain the updated width of the window

Comment: @Haversine: you're over-thinking this. `global WW; WW=canvas.winfo_width()` will cause `WW` to always have the current width.